# Change iteration method to recursion to calculate Polygon area

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, polygon

I did some coding in Java to calculate the area of Polygon. In my code, i'm using iteration "for" to get the input of coordinate value of X and Y in ArrayList. My code calculation run successfully and I did get the correct output.

My problem is that I want to change my code to use recursion so that computeArea(ArrayList c, int size) can be call recursively and I don't want to use an iteration "for" in this method.

I would be really appreciate to those who can show me how to change this method from iteration to recursive.

Thanks.

Below is my code for Polygon.java

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Polygon
{
private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> corners;
private double area;
private double adding;
private double minus;
private double exAdding;
private double exMinus;

public Polygon()
{
    corners = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
    area = 0;
    adding = 0;
    minus = 0;
    exAdding = 0;
    exMinus = 0;
}

//add point to the array
public void add (Point2D.Double p)
{
    corners.add(p);
}

//computes area of polygon
public double getArea()
{
    return computeArea(corners, corners.size());
}

public double computeArea(ArrayList<Point2D.Double> c, int size)
{
    if (size < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            double xA = c.get(i).getX();
            double yA = c.get(i).getY();
            double xB = c.get(i+1).getX();
            double yB = c.get(i+1).getY();

            exAdding = c.get(size-1).getX()*c.get(size-size).getY();
            adding = adding + xA*yB; 

            exMinus = c.get(size-1).getY()*c.get(size-size).getX();
            minus = minus + yA*xB;

            //System.out.println("test adding : " + adding);
        }
        //System.out.println("extra adding : " + exAdding);
        area = Math.abs((adding+exAdding) - (minus+exMinus));

        return area/2;
    }
}
```

}

This is my code for PolygonTester.java

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class PolygonTester
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //create square
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.add(new Point2D.Double(10, 20));
    p.add(new Point2D.Double(20, 20));
    p.add(new Point2D.Double(20, 10));
    p.add(new Point2D.Double(10, 10));

    System.out.println("Area : " + p.getArea());
    System.out.println("Expected : 100");


    //create square
    Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
    p1.add(new Point2D.Double(3, 4));
    p1.add(new Point2D.Double(5, 11));
    p1.add(new Point2D.Double(12, 8));
    p1.add(new Point2D.Double(9, 5));
    p1.add(new Point2D.Double(5, 6));

    System.out.println("Area : " + p1.getArea());
    System.out.println("Expected : 30");

    //regular hexagon with radius 1
    p = new Polygon();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        p.add(new Point2D.Double(Math.sin(i*Math.PI/3), Math.cos(i*Math.PI/3)));
    }

    System.out.println("Area : " + p.getArea());
    System.out.println("Expected : " + 3*Math.sqrt(3)/2);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you write down, why do you want to use recursion? This piece of code looks good for me, recursion will add more complexity to your solution, calling method is slower than simple `for`.  And honestly I don't see option how to include recursion in your code - it's useful for processing trees etc. not plain array.

Comment: hi jan, i would like to learn how to use recursive instead of iteration in my code. So that, i can thinks and use recursive instead of iteration only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your program

```
    public void recursionMethod(ArrayList<Point2D.Double> c, int size, int count){
      if(count<size-1){
        double xA = c.get(count).getX();
        double yA = c.get(count).getY();
        double xB = c.get(count+1).getX();
        double yB = c.get(count+1).getY();

        exAdding = c.get(size-1).getX()*c.get(size-size).getY();
        adding = adding + xA*yB; 

        exMinus = c.get(size-1).getY()*c.get(size-size).getX();
        minus = minus + yA*xB;
        recursionMethod(c, size, count+1);
       }
    }
```

and call this method instead of your for loop

```
recursionMethod(c, size, 0);
```

Comment: i did this, but i'm not quite understand where should "i" refer to? since in my previous code.."i" is refer to int in the for loop.

Comment: thanks candy! got it as recursion..i want to vote your answer as solved, but i'm not allowed since my reputation has not achieved 15 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be missing the point of recursion. While it is true that most iterative methods can be replaced with recursion and vice versa, in many cases one technique or the other is a natural fit for your problem. In your case this is naturally an iterative problem: the polygon is defined by its vertices and calculating the area involves visiting each one consecutively.

I would suggest picking a more naturally recursive problem if you wish to practice recursion. In general the form of recursion is:

```
result recursiveproblem(context)
    if context is simple enough to have obvious answer
        return obvious answer
    else
        break context into smaller pieces
        call recursive problem on each of the smaller pieces
        combine the answers
```

So this fits situations where there is a natural simple state with an obvious answer as well as ways of breaking down and combining answers.

The canonical example is factorial. By definition factorial(0) = 1 and factorial(n) = n * factorial(n - 1)

Already that looks very naturally recursive in a way that calculating area doesn't.

Comment: Yeah..i still have not get the grip on recursion yet. Need to practice more so that i will be able to understand the appropriate use of it. Thanks sprinter for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I have just been looking at using recursion to calculate centroids. I have written the following recursive solution for the equations listed in the Wikipedia page for [Centroids of Polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon). You will see that you need to use the first two 2D points on the list to calculate areas etc and then add to the same function applied to the remainder of the list of 2D points. This seems to me to meet the criterion set by "sprinter" (but perhaps I am missing something).

The following F# code generates a tuple containing the area of the polygon and the two centroids:

```
let AddTuple3 (a, b, c) (d, e, f) = (a+d,b+e,c+f)
let Comb3 (X1, Y1) (X2, Y2) = 
   let A = (X1 * Y2 - X2 * Y1) / 2.0
   (A, (X1 + X2) * A / 3.0, (Y1 + Y2) * A / 3.0)

let SecProp2D PtLst = 
   let rec RecSecProp2D PtLst = 
      match PtLst with 
      | [A] -> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
      | B::C -> AddTuple3 (Comb3 B C.Head) (RecSecProp2D C)
      | _ -> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
   let (A, B, C) = RecSecProp2D PtLst
   (A, B/A, C/A)

// Testing...
let PtLst1 = [(0.0,0.0);(2.0,0.0);(2.0,5.0);(0.0,5.0);(0.0,0.0)] // 2x5 rectangle
printfn "Recursive Area, Cx & Cy are %A" (SecProp2D PtLst1)
```

You can play with it on [dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net).